# Output data like WP's plugin installer/updater

Tags: php

I want to update my plugin and have proper feedback, like the WordPress update/upgrade mechanism. How is this effect done?

Essentially I have a script I want to run that has lots of processing, and with each run through the loop, output another line to the screen. Is this done with the output buffer?

Comment: Did this solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks, Brian, I looked at flushing the buffer and managed to use the straight PHP functions to get the result I needed. The trick was outputting my feedback in the right spot on the page to have it shown in the middle, where you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, WordPress uses output buffering for displaying these messages. There's a nifty function you can use within your loop called show_message() which utilizes wp_ob_end_flush_all();

```
function show_message($message) {
    if ( is_wp_error($message) ){
        if ( $message->get_error_data() )
            $message = $message->get_error_message() . ': ' . $message->get_error_data();
        else
            $message = $message->get_error_message();
    }
    echo "<p>$message</p>\n";
    wp_ob_end_flush_all();
    flush();
}
```

You might wish to abstract this to your own function as there is [a feature in the queue](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12254) to migrate this to a method within WP_Error. It's possible this function will become deprecated in the future.